# Removing JOIN from SELECT query

Tags: sql, select, join

I have a SELECT query that contains an INNER JOIN. I am looking for a way to create the same query but without any kind of JOIN. Here is my current query;

`SELECT loan.duedate, loan.no, student.name FROM loan
 INNER JOIN student ON loan.no = student.no
 ORDER BY loan.duedate DESC LIMIT 1`

Would this be possible and how would I create this?

Comment: Why do you want to avoid the join?

Comment: Why? Whats the problem?

Comment: I asked the same question, it's part of some work I was given but I can't think of a way to create the statement without the join. It confused me too

Comment: Student assignment or actual work?!? Still an odd requirement...

Comment: Without understanding why this is needed, we cannot give a sensible answer: it is likely any syntactic rearrangement would hit the same issue that is underlying the desire to avoid a join (in the end anything equivalent is going to have an equivalent execution plan).

Comment: Student work but not a marked assignment. One question asks to create this query with a join and the next question asks to create the same query without the join... No idea why they're asking for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ignoring 'why' you would want to do it and just approaching this as a quiz question, you could use a sub-select instead of the JOIN if the JOIN is 1:1;

```
SELECT 
    loan.duedate, 
    loan.no, 
    (SELECT student.name FROM student WHERE student.no = loan.no) AS name 
FROM 
    loan
ORDER BY 
    loan.duedate DESC 
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Implicit join, but maybe it doesn't count (what do I know...)

Comment: Thanks, this is what I'm looking for. Apologies for the stupid question, unfortunately I can't control the questions/work I'm given!

Answer (score 0):

Simple enough to convert but Inner Join makes more sense.

```
SELECT loan.duedate, loan.no, student.name 
FROM loan l,
student s 
Where l.no = s.no
ORDER BY l.duedate DESC 
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: This is a join! (Just the older join syntax...)

Comment: I'm just making the assumption that the assignment meant not to use the word join.